# How do enemies respawn in Shattered Pixel Dungeon?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

In *Pixel Dungeon*, one enemy would respawn every 50 turns (25 turns at night). But many changes were made to Shattered PD. to prevent farming, and I think someone told me respawning is diferent in Shattered PD. When do enemies respawn in Shattered Pixel Dungeon? And if they do, is it on every floor, or only the one the player is currently on?

Comment: Your best bet would be diving into the [source code](https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon/tree/master), and looking up keywords such as "spawn" or "delay".

Comment: @uriyabsc Man, was hoping not to have to, but I think it's gonna be the only way.

Comment: Floors other than the one you're on are effectively frozen until you return to them.

Comment: @User23415 Ah, thank you